# Why is Firebug unable to detect some JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firebug

I have written JavaScript outside the `<body>` end tag. Firebug is unable to detect the JavaScript and I am unable to detect the JavaScript error.

Here is my code:

```
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

function displayIFrameContent()
{   
    var iFrame = document.getElementById("link");
    var if1= "<iframe src='http://leadmarket.hol.es/forms/solar-power.php?adv_id=" + <?php echo($fetch_users_data['id']); ?>; 
    var if2= "<iframe src='http://leadmarket.hol.es/forms/kitchen-installation.php?adv_id=" + <?php echo($fetch_users_data['id']); ?>; 
    var if3= "<iframe src='http://leadmarket.hol.es/forms/conservatory.php?adv_id=" + <?php echo($fetch_users_data['id']);; ?>; 

    var host = document.getElementById("host");
    var subId = document.getElementById("subid");
    var errorClass = "box form-validation-error border-width-2";

    if(host.value == "")
        changeClass("host", errorClass);

    if(host.value != "")
    {       
        var iFrameEnd = " width='280' height='330' frameborder='0' scrolling='no'></iframe>";

        var leadTypeSelect = document.getElementById("leadType");
        var leadTypeValue = leadTypeSelect.options[leadTypeSelect.selectedIndex].value;

        iFrame.value  = "";

        if(leadTypeValue == 1)
            iFrame.value  = if1 + "&" + "sub_id=" + subId.value + "&source=" + host.value + "'" + iFrameEnd;

        if(leadTypeValue == 2)
            iFrame.value  = if2 + "&" + "sub_id=" + subId.value + "&source=" + host.value + "'" + iFrameEnd;

        if(leadTypeValue == 3)
            iFrame.value  = if3 + "&" + "sub_id=" + subId.value + "&source=" + host.value + "'" + iFrameEnd;
    }       
}


function changeClass(id, classname) 
{
    document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("class", classname);
}   
</script>
</html>
```

Your help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you closing `</script>` the `<script>` tag?

Comment: Well you are now that you've updated the question.

Comment: @gotnull i wrote that...because i forgot to give 4 spaces..it was not displaying

Comment: I think you've got your `<script>` tag in the wrong place. Instead of after the `<body>` tag make it the last element INSIDE your `<body>` tag like `<html><head/><body><script></script></body></html>`

Comment: @jasonscript tried not working..:(

Answer (score 0):

The code above contains PHP tags, which cause some syntax errors. In this case the Script panel just shows a message "No Javascript on this page". You should make sure they are interpreted by PHP before they are output to the browser.

Also JavaScript syntax errors are listed within the [Console Panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel). Make sure you have the option *Show JavaScript Errors* checked to see them.

Furthermore there's a detailed [description about script debugging](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Debugging) available within the Firebug wiki.

Sebastian